# How to represent NSUUID as a string?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I convert a `NSUUID` to `NSString`?

```
NSString *url = [self mysql_process:ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID];

- (NSString*)mysql_process:(NSUUID *)beacon_id
{

    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://path_to_php_file/mysql.php?id=%@", beacon_id];
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return strResult;

}
```

When I try to `NSLog` the `URL` im getting a pointer, which shows me my `NSUUID`, `ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID` in this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`NSUUID`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a method: [`-(NSString*)UUIDString;`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUUID/UUIDString).
So:

```
NSString *uuidString = [yourNSUUID UUIDString]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! thats exactly what i was looking for. Piece of code helped me really.

Answer (score 1):

swift 3 version

**Ex:**

let uuidStringValue = "12345678-1111-2222-3333-4567891012B4"

let proximityUUID = NSUUID(uuidString: uuidStringValue)

Answer (score 0):

If you want NSString from NSUUID. Use UUIDString of NSUUID...

```
    NSUUID *uuidStringRef = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
    NSString *stringRef = [uuidStringRef UUIDString];//you can replace uuidStringRef with your ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID
```

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: thanks for the answer! I realy googled around and found something like your answer but it didnt really helped me, because im newbie to iOS and Objective-C and still cant understand every single concept of the language.

Answer (score 0):

```
   NSString *url = [self mysql_process:ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID];

- (NSString*)mysql_process:(NSUUID *)beacon_id  {

    **NSString *strDeviceUUID = [beacon_id UUIDString];** // Converts NSUUID to UUIDString format

    NSLog(@"beacon_id : %@ strDeviceUUID : %@ ", beacon_id,strDeviceUUID);

    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://path_to_php_file/mysql.php?id=%@", strDeviceUUID];
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return strResult;
}
```

This function is present in NSUUID.h file of Foundation frameworks.

```
/* Return a string description of the UUID, such as "E621E1F8-C36C-495A-93FC-0C247A3E6E5F" */
- (NSString *) UUIDString;
```