# NSUUID to NSString from (CBPeripheral *)aPeripheral

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I want to save the string version of the NSUUID from a CBPeripheral.

I try this:

```
NSString *uuidString = aPeripheral.UUID;
```

But a warning appears:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing NSString with an expression of type CFUUIDRef

- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)aPeripheral  {

    NSLog(@"method didConnectPeripheral %@ " , aPeripheral.UUID);

    NSString *uuidString = aPeripheral.UUID;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to represent NSUUID as a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293860/how-to-represent-nsuuid-as-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-UUID` method of `CBPeripheral` returns a `CFUUIDRef`, not an `NSString`, and is also deprecated as of iOS 7.1. If you need to use it, either store it in a `CFUUIDRef`, or use `CFUUIDCreateString` and bridge it to an `NSString`.

Answer (score 1):

A UUID is no string (even it is represented as a string very often.)

You can convert it into a `CFStringRef` with `CFUUIDCreateString()`;